# What would group.instance.id should be for Kafka consumer static membership?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, consumer

We are trying to set up static membership for Kafka consumers to account for container maintenance upgrades. Every once in while containers will be deployed with improvement which can take down consumer app instances in random order. The termination process for upgrade is SIGKILL while creating a duplicate copy of running instance. This causes rebalance when instance leaves the group & joins the group.

Static membership is helpful for such scenarios. I want to know whether group.instance.id should be set up unique to each instance of consumer app ( appname-instance-1, appname-instnace-2 et al.) or it should be unique to consumer group ( similar to consumer group id ie one instance id for entire consumer group)

Is there any other config we need to change from broker side/consumer side for faster re-balancing ?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Image taken from [KIP-345](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-345%3A+Introduce+static+membership+protocol+to+reduce+consumer+rebalances)

- `group.instance.id` is an identifier for a consumer, hence should be unique at consumer level
- `group.id` is an identifier for a group, hence unique at group level

Comment: What does it mean at consumer level ? Consumer can have multiple app instances running. Should it be unique to instance like I asked (appname-instance-1, appname-instance-2...) ?

Comment: Yes it should be unique per instance of the consumer ...

Answer (score 1):

**group.instance.id** is configured by users to uniquely identify their consumer instances

If you use kafka streams, internally it adds the the - suffix appended.

Example:

```
group.instance.id = kafka-streams-instance-1
```

if this app has 3 threads, internally it assign:

```
kafka-streams-instance-1-1
kafka-streams-instance-1-2
kafka-streams-instance-1-3
```